# Mongodb sharding dropping writes

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-update

I have a set of documents containing counters that are periodically incremented using an upsert $inc command.

I have several nodes as part of a sharded cluster.

With sharding switched off for the database, all updates seem to work fine and the counters are incremented correctly.

As soon as I enable sharding for the database and its collections, the vast majority of updates seem to be discarded. Even when I set write concern to 1, and I get a write receipt like this, which seems to indicate the write succeeded, it still doesn't increment the counter:

```
{ writeback: 51dc4e950000000000014aa2,
     writebackSince: 574,
     instanceIdent: 'mongobig-4-1:27018',
     updatedExisting: true,
     n: 1,
     lastOp: { _bsontype: 'Timestamp', low_: 16, high_: 1373393554 },
     connectionId: 925,
     err: null,
     ok: 1 }
```

What is happening to the update commands when sharding?

Comment: What version of mongodb are you using?

Comment: db version v2.4.4
Tue Jul  9 18:50:00.415 git version: 4ec1fb96702c9d4c57b1e06dd34eb73a16e407d2